# Creating new minimum and maximum values to be consistent across 4 DEMs

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.7

I have 4 DEMs (LIDAR, 5M, 10M AND 30M resolutions) all with the same geographical extent and I want to compare the differences in resolution using 4 layouts. I want to have the same minimum and maximum elevations for each DEM. They vary slightly but all the minimum values are around 1520 and all the maximum values are around 3450. Someone told me I can use the Con tool to make all elevations below and above certain values NoData but I am having difficulty figuring out how to properly use this tool (my SQL expression is always giving me an error when I verify it so I am not even sure how to go about doing this). I suppose I could just change the numbers in the legend but I want to do it properly and actually have the same range of elevation values for each DEM.

How should I proceed?

I am using Esri's ArcMap 10.7.1.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your SQL expression

Comment: Rather than creating new data, in your symbology use either the same classification (classified renderer), or use the same statistics (stretched renderer).